# Edit CSS of HTML video controls

Tags: html, css, html5-video

When I try to inspect the default HTML video controls in Google Chrome it doesn't show up in Chrome's developer tools.

All I want to do is move the position of the default HTML video controls without creating complete custom controls with HTML, CSS and Javascript. Looking through the posts it doesn't seem like it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling browser-native video controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184846/styling-browser-native-video-controls)

Comment: You need to define your own elements ( div's, buttons etc. ) and bind the events to them. This will give your controls more uniform look across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't style the browser's default video controls.