# HTML how to edit the layout of video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a simple video in my website

```
<video width="100%" class="posted_vid">
        <source src="uploaded_videos/<?php echo $Video; ?>">
</video>
```

Now this videos looks like a default HTML video like in here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
How can i change the design of controller to make it look like YouTube or Facebook videos?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184846/styling-browser-native-video-controls

Comment: You can use Javascript like this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop and style it with CSS. That is the closest you can get!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to alter the controls for the native HTML video component.

The only way to do this would be to create your own video component using either [Web Components](https://www.webcomponents.org) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) etc.