# HTML video tag shifts position of controls

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

Is it possible to modify the position of the video controls in css/js?

I have a video that is 960x960 in resolution, and I need to hide the bottom 25% of the video since they are just black. I am thinking of wrapping the `<video>` in a `<div>` so and set the height of div to be 75% of video and setting the `overflow: hidden`

But once I do this, the video controls are hidden under the `<div>` and i can no longer use the controls.

Is there a way to simply change the position of the controls? Or do I have to style the controls myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184846/styling-browser-native-video-controls

Comment: @MichaelCoker I guess I can't simply move the native controls then.